# Filter beween array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array of dates:

```
const dates = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3', 'date4', 'date5'];
```

and a function that gets two values and returns true if two dates are in same week

```
function isSameWeek(a,b){
// some code
 return true or false;
}
```

I want to filter the `dates` array in a way that none of it's values are in same week(one for each week).

For example if `isSameWeek('date1', 'date2')=true` , the filtered Array should be `filtered=['date1', 'date3', 'date4', 'date5']`

Helps are appreciated :)

Comment: Are you saying that the leftmost value "wins"? Because there are various solutions to choose from. Are the dates ordered?

Comment: No it doesn't matter , just need one value for each week

Comment: Then you could use a function that returns the week number, and maintain a set to ensure a week only appears once.

Comment: That's the issue , kinda forced to use `isSameWeek` func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dates are sorted, this can be accomplished with a single pass:

```js
// monkey patching here for example sake (ignore this)
Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function() {
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate()));
  var dayNum = d.getUTCDay() || 7;
  d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - dayNum);
  var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(),0,1));
  return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7);
}

const isSameWeek = (a, b) => a.getWeekNumber() == b.getWeekNumber();

function getWeeklyDates(dates)
{
  // can remove the sort() if already sorted
  dates.sort((a, b) => a - b)
  // filter out in a single pass
  return dates.filter((date, index) => {
    return index > 0 ? !isSameWeek(date, dates[index - 1]) : true; // not in the same week
  });
}

const dates = [
  new Date('2020-01-01'),
  new Date('2020-02-01'),
  new Date('2020-01-03'),
  new Date('2020-03-05'),
  new Date('2020-03-03')
];

console.log(getWeeklyDates(dates));
```

Comment: was just thinking about this `dates.filter((a, i) => i ? isSameWeek(a, dates[i - 1]) : true);`

Comment: @PersianIronwood that's a great suggestion; updated my answer, thanks! think i need more sleep

Comment: should be changed to `!isSameWeek`

Answer (score 2):

You should check out Array's [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```js
return dates.reduce((unique, date) => {
  if (unique.some(it => isSameWeek(it, date)) return unique;
  return [...unique, date];
}, [])
```

Comment: Also, if the dates are ordered, it'll be enough to just preserve the previous date and check against that.